# Two date values cause duplicates

Tags: views, 8

I am using drupal 8 and have a date field with the values limited to two.

This works well until I have to put it into a view. When I do so, I get two view rows, one sorted by the value of the first value and another sorted by the second value.

I have tried to use aggregation and Count Distinct, but I get a huge error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_term__FIELD_NAME_1.FIELD_NAME_1_'
>   in 'field list': SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT
>   taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_term__FIELD_NAME_1.FIELD_NAME_1_
>   AS taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_te,
>   node_field_data.title AS node_field_data_title,
>   node__field_address.field_address_value AS
>   node__field_address_field_address_value,
>   node__field_NAME_3.field_NAME_3_value AS
>   node__field_NAME_3_field_NAME_3_value, node_field_data.created AS
>   node_field_data_created, 1 AS expression FROM {node_field_data}
>   node_field_data LEFT JOIN {node__field_NAME_2} node__field_NAME_2 ON
>   node_field_data.nid = node__field_NAME_2.entity_id AND
>   (node__field_NAME_2.deleted = :views_join_condition_0 AND
>   node__field_NAME_2.langcode = node_field_data.langcode) LEFT JOIN
>   {taxonomy_term_field_data} taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2
>   ON node__field_NAME_2.field_NAME_2_target_id =
>   taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2.tid LEFT JOIN
>   {taxonomy_term__FIELD_NAME_1}
>   taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_term__FIELD_NAME_1
>   ON taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2.tid =
>   taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_term__FIELD_NAME_1.entity_id
>   AND
>   (taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_term__FIELD_NAME_1.deleted
>   = :views_join_condition_2 AND taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_term__FIELD_NAME_1.langcode
>   = taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2.langcode) LEFT JOIN {node__field_address} node__field_address ON node_field_data.nid =
>   node__field_address.entity_id AND (node__field_address.deleted =
>   :views_join_condition_4 AND node__field_address.langcode =
>   node_field_data.langcode) LEFT JOIN {node__field_NAME_3}
>   node__field_NAME_3 ON node_field_data.nid =
>   node__field_NAME_3.entity_id AND (node__field_NAME_3.deleted =
>   :views_join_condition_6 AND node__field_NAME_3.langcode =
>   node_field_data.langcode) WHERE (( (node_field_data.status =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (node_field_data.type IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) )) GROUP BY
>   taxonomy_term_field_data_node__field_NAME_2__taxonomy_te,
>   node_field_data_title, node_field_data.nid,
>   node__field_address_field_address_value,
>   node__field_NAME_3_field_NAME_3_value, node_field_data_created)
>   subquery; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => recent [:views_join_condition_0] => 0
>   [:views_join_condition_2] => 0 [:views_join_condition_4] => 0
>   [:views_join_condition_6] => 0 )

How can I have two date values with only one view result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What the error you are getting can you post?

Comment: @CodeNext Error posted.